# N64 Transfer Pak

Tags: nintendo-64

I recently received an N64 transfer pak. When I looked at the label it was orange, so I looked it up and found that it is a Japanese transfer pak. I am planning on buying an N64 and was wondering whether a Japanese transfer pak would work on a PAL system.

Comment: Unfortunately there is no hard evidence to say whether it will or won't work. A lot of it depends on the age of the machine, of the accessory, whether they're new or second-hand etc. The best I can say is either get a Japanese N64, spend another $xx to get another transfer pak, or just try it out and see for yourself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It would appear that the Transfer Paks are compatible no matter which region the system is from.

I'm gathering this information from [this article](http://www.ign.com/articles/2000/03/07/transfer-pak) (IGN) which states,

"The Japanese Transfer Pak is completely compatible with US Nintendo 64 systems and games that support the unit."

Comment: Here are my test results regarding Transfer Pak Region compatibility. https://sites.google.com/site/consoleprotocols/home/gamers/n64-region-info Basically confirms the above.